# Is is possible to export Inkscape files for inDesign?

Tags: inkscape

I was wondering if it was possible to export anything built in Inkscape to inDesign CS or CS5. If it is possible, how can I get it to work?

Comment: You might want to add a little more info for folks that might know Inkscape but not inDesign. What file types could you use? Inkscape is more similar to Illustrator. It works with svg file, but can export to a number of other formats, png, pdf, ps, wmf, and xcf just to name a few.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Adobe [[1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6bd1a.html)], InDesign does not support importing SVG files. It does, however, support importing EPS files, which Inkscape can export to (just choose EPS from the drop-down box in the "Save as ..." dialog).

Answer (score 2):

You can import EPS files into inDesign. In Inkscape go to file > save as, then choose EPS from the dropdown menu.

In inDesign, go to file > place and choose your exported EPS.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another file format that works well for exporting to InDesign, it is PDF,
to save as PDF, select file > save as, then choose Portable Document Format(.*pdf) from the drop down menu.

PDF documents can be placed in InDesign. Even If you choose to combine PDFs as a single document individual pages can be placed from this document in InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is if you have also Illustrator on your computer. You can Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V from Inkscape to Illustrator and then Ctrl+C,Ctrl+V from Illustrator to InDesign. You will get fully editable graphics.

Comment: excellent answer, BUT I "only" have inkscape and indesign. How to export a vector graphic from inkscape to indesign, sothat the vectors are editable without having illustrator???

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember Photoshop can import SVG. So inDesign should too.
There are many discussions on this theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, EPS is probably the answer. However, in case you need to import SVG images into InDesign, you can also use this [SVG plug-in for Adobe CS](http://svg.scand.com).